# macOS (M1) - Create custom shortcuts keyboard (not from recently open folders)

Tags: keyboard, dock, shortcuts-app

i want to create custom shortcuts to open folders in my mac M1 2020 13.3, so i goes to system pref' -> keyboard shortcuts -> App Shortcuts -> Create my key combination and name my folder.

But , its allow to open it through my combination key **Only** if i just opened it before, and its minimize to my dock, it's **Not** reopen it if i close the folder.

**My Question**: How can i make a shortcuts which will open my folders **Always** , even if I did not open the folder once from the moment I turned on the computer, and it is not in my dock (minimize)... i didnt find anything which could help me here! thank you!

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the shortcut you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Automator.app" for this. Create a "Workflow", place a "Run Shell Script" with the content like:

```
open /PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER
```

Save it and assign a shortcut to it.

[image: Automator Workflow to open Downloads folder]

You can also make it in Shortcuts.app by placing the "Shell Script" there. `open /PATH/TO/FOLDER` works in such way that it brings the Finder to front with that folder opened (if it was opened in the background). If not, new Finder window with that folder is opened.